# How to solve $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{-n^2}}{\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}$

Tags: calculus

I've tried to solve this but I'm getting infinity upon infinity i.e. indeterminate, and its answer is infinity.
So please give me a correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want to compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{2^{-n^2}}{\displaystyle\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}$.

**Hint**: Note that $\displaystyle\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2} \le \sum_{r = (n+1)^2}^{\infty}2^{-r} = 2 \cdot 2^{-(n+1)^2} = 2^{-n^2-2n}$. (This is true since the second sum contains every term that the first sum contains, along with a few more).

So what can you say about the ratio $\dfrac{2^{-n^2}}{\displaystyle\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}2^{-k^2}}$?

Comment: Yeah.ofcourse infinity. But i dont get. How 2^(-n^2-2n) ??

Comment: The second summation is a geometric series. Use the formula for the sum of a geometric series and then simplify the result.